# Azure Bot Service: 'build.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: azure-bot-service

When I am trying to create my web-app bot, i am unable to find the build.cmd files (among the many files that are shown on those youtube tutorial videos) and i am unable to redeploy my bot after making changes on the online code editor. Please help! Thank you. 
[e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtwsE.png)

** I found that it might be because i chose the Node.js SDK version instead of C#. How can i re-deploy my online code editor scripts for the Node.js version?

Comment: Can you  clarify a bit more? You went on azure to create the bot, then  what? Pulled the  code down to locally make changes? Now you want to redeploy it to azure?

Comment: A number of the youtube videos are severely outdated  (even ones as recent as the beginning of this year). can you link what videos  you were watching?

Comment: Hi @JJ_Wailes, 

I created a Web App Bot on azure, then i went to the online code editor (under the Build option) to edit some codes like change the DefaultNoAnswer replies and so on. But afterwards, I could not find a way to redeploy my scripts. The instructions written in the Build option said to run 'build.cmd' inside the console to save and redeploy my changes. BUt there wasnt any 'build.cmd' file available.

I think this is bc i chose Node.js SDK while creating my bot instead of C#. May i know how can we redeploy our scripts through the online code editor if we are using node.js sdk?

Comment: If you changed the code actually  ON azure, and didn't pull it down to your local machine, there is nothing to "redeploy". To (re)deploy, you're taking local code and pushing it to the azure servers. Your code never came off the azure servers. It's got nothing to do with the language you're using.

Comment: Is there any issues with your code? Ignore the whole 'redeploy' bit. If you change your code, and save it, and go back to 'test in webchat', does your bot reflect your changes?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to "redeploy" your code. I'm not sure what you're following as a tutorial, but that is an incorrect instruction. Code that is already on Azure is already deployed. You don't need to deploy it.

To get the 'build.cmd' bit out of the way: There is a portion on Azure that says this:
[image]

This is wrong. If the bot is C#, you have to run 'build.cmd' to recompile all the files, but if it's node, you can ignore it. I'll be reaching out to a member of the azure team to correct this.

As to making changes on  Azure. If you click the link from the image above, you go to the online code editor. You can make changes to  your code there, and simply save the files. For example, create the bot in Azure, then test in webchat:

**NEW BOT, CREATED ON AZURE:**

[image: original test in webchat]

Once the deployment/creation is completed, you can go into the code editor and make changes:

**MY CODE IN THE EDITOR**

[image: edited code]

At this point, you want to watch one thing. In the upper right is a small icon that will either say 'dirty' or 'saved'. You can see in my image that it says 'saved'. Azure will auto save changes you make periodically, so you don't need to save yourself. Once that icon says 'saved', you hit the 'run' button on the vertical bar on the left (the 'play' button, top button in the lower section):

**SAVE ICON**

[image: save button]

Two things will happen at this point: first, the output pane will open on the code editor, telling you that your server is being restarted:

**OUTPUT PANE**
[image: output pane]

And the second is that a new window will open, going to the page *YOURBOTNAME*.azurewebsites.net. As bots created on Azure don't have static webpages, this will show a simple page with  a "code":"ResourceNotFound". You can close this window.

Go back to azure, and to the 'test in webchat' for your bot. Hit the 'Start over' button on 'test in webchat'.

**MY NEW WELCOME MESSAGE, FROM ONLINE CODE CHANGES**
[image: changed bot dialog]